# Перегрузка оператора + для класса комплексных чисел

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, перегрузка-операторов

Хочу перегрузить оператор +, но при попытке вызвать его, что-то идет не так и компилятор выдает ошибку invalid operands of types 'Complex*' and 'Complex*' to binary 'operator+'.

```
class Complex
{
private:
double real;
double imagine;

public:
Complex()
{
    real = 0;
    imagine = 0;    
}
Complex(double a, double b)
{
    real = a;
    imagine = b;    
}

double getReal()
{
            return real;
}

Complex operator+(const Complex& other)
{
    this->real+=other.real;
    this->imagine+=other.imagine;
    return *this;   
}
```

Память под объекты выделяю динамически, оператор вызываю так:

```
C_Complex=A_Complex+B_Complex;
```

Comment: Судя по всему, вы догадались складывать **указатели** на Complex...

Comment: А каким образом сделать так, чтоб складывались именно объекты?

Comment: Код страдает от проблем с константной корректностью, которые еще вылезут, но ошибка, как вам ясно сказал компилятор, вызвана тем, что вы почему-то пытаетесь складывать указатели. Откуда у вас вообще взялись указатели? Что такое `C_Complex`, `A_Complex`, `B_Complex`? Почему в вопросе нет этой информации??

Comment: А зачем вам вообще использовать указатели (и, видимо, `new`/`delete`)? Не лучше взять просто объекты `Complex`?

Comment: Ну, без динамической памяти все отлично работает, хочеться узнать как сделать те же действия с её использованием

Comment: `*C_Complex=*A_Complex+*B_Complex;` - но это просто извращение!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как следует из сообщения об ошибке, вы пытаетесь выполнить бинарную операцию `+` для указателей, которая для них не определена. То есть переменные `C_Complex`, `A_Complex` и `B_Complex`, похоже, являются указателями, а вам нужно сложить сами объекты, адресуемые этими указателями.

Поэтому попробуйте написать

```
*C_Complex = *A_Complex + *B_Complex;
```

Имейте в виду, что в определении бинарного оператора `+` для объектов класса `Comp[lex` у вас имеется логическая ошибка. На самом деле, фактически, вы перегрузили оператор `+=` вместо оператора `+`, так как левый операнд операции у вас изменяется.

```
Complex operator+(const Complex& other)
{
    this->real+=other.real;
    this->imagine+=other.imagine;
    return *this;   
}
```

Правильно было бы определить этот оператор как дружественную функцию

```
friend Complex operator +( const Complex &left, const Complex &right )
{
    return { left.real + right.real, left.imagine + right.imagine };   
}
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>

class Complex
{
private:
    double real;
    double imagine;

public:
    Complex() : Complex( 0.0, 0.0 )
    {
    }

    Complex( double a, double b ) : real( a ), imagine( b )
    {
    }

    friend Complex operator +( const Complex &left, const Complex &right )
    {
        return { left.real + right.real, left.imagine + right.imagine };   
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Complex &c )
    {
        return os << "{ " << c.real << ", " << c.imagine << " }";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << Complex( 10, 10 ) + Complex( 5, 5 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
{ 15, 15 }
```

Comment: @Ivan9999: Не "помогло", а вы тем самым скорее всего просто "замели ошибку под ковер", вместо того, чтобы исправить ее. Еще раз: откуда у вас вообще взялись указатели?

Comment: Использовал их при выделении динамической памяти под обьект:                              
     Complex *A_Complex = new Complex();

Comment: @Ivan9999: Так а зачем вы выделяли именно *динамическую* память под эти объекты?

Comment: Так сказать, по своей прихоти, а в этом есть что-то плохое?